# A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object

Tags: telebot

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import os

API_TOKEN = ''
admin_id = 
channel_id = 
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)
p_inform = ''
v_inform = ''

def start_kb():
    kb_start = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True, row_width=5)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Послать фото")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Послать видео")
    kb_start.add(btn1, btn2)
    return kb_start

def wait_kb():
    kb_start = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True, row_width=5)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("/start")
    kb_start.add(btn1)
    return kb_start

def a_d_kb():
    kb = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    a = types.KeyboardButton('Одобрить')
    d = types.KeyboardButton('Проклясть')
    kb.add(a,d)
    return kb

def terminate(cur):
    f=open('logs.txt','r').readlines()
    for i in f:
        if i == cur:
            f.pop(i)
    with open('logs.txt','w') as F:
        F.writelines(f)
    return 'Успешно'

def first():
    with open('logs.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        return f.readline()
current_file, current_mess_author, current_mess_info, current_mess_name = '', '', '', ''
    
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(mes):
    if mes.chat.id != admin_id:
        bot.send_message(mes.chat.id, text='Приветствую тебя! Друг)', reply_markup=start_kb())
    else:
        kb = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
        a = types.KeyboardButton('Поработать')
        kb.add(a)
        bot.send_message(mes.chat.id, text='ПРивет, ПАпОЧКа', reply_markup=kb)


                
    
def log(content, id, info):
    with open('logs.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write('\n'+ content + '|' + info + '|@' + id)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text(mes):
    if mes.text == 'Послать фото':
        bot.send_message(mes.chat.id, text=f'Подпиши фото')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(mes, p_info)

    if mes.text == 'Послать видео':
        bot.send_message(mes.chat.id, text=f'Подпиши видео')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(mes, v_info)

    if mes.text == "Поработать":
        if os.path.getsize(r"C:\Users\temai\test2\logs.txt") == 0:
            bot.send_message(admin_id, text='Новых публикаций нет', reply_markup=[wait_kb])
        else:
            global current_file, current_mess_author, current_mess_info, current_mess_name
            current_file = first()
            current_mess_name = str(current_file.split('|')[0])
            current_mess_info = str(current_file.split('|')[1])
            current_mess_author = str(current_file.split('|')[2])
            if current_mess_name[0] == 'p':
                photo = open(r"C:\Users\temai\test2\images" + f"\{current_mess_name}", 'rb')
                bot.send_photo(admin_id, photo, caption=f'текст к фото:{current_mess_info}, создатель: {current_mess_author}', reply_markup=a_d_kb)
            if current_mess_name[0] == 'v':
                video = open(r"C:\Users\temai\test2\video" + f"\{current_mess_name}", 'rb')
                bot.send_video(admin_id, video, caption=f'текст к видео:{current_mess_info}, создатель: {current_mess_author}', reply_markup=a_d_kb) 

    if mes.text == 'Одобрить':
        if current_file[0] == 'p':
            photo = open(r"C:\Users\temai\test2\images" + f"\{current_mess_name}", 'rb')
            bot.send_photo(channel_id, photo, caption=f'{current_mess_info}\nCоздатель: {current_mess_author}')
            os.remove(r"C:\Users\temai\test2\images" + f"\{current_mess_name}")
            terminate(current_file)
        if current_file[0] == 'v':
            video = open(r"C:\Users\temai\test2\video" + f"\{current_mess_name}", 'rb')
            bot.send_video(channel_id, video, caption=f'{current_mess_info}\nCоздатель: {current_mess_author}')
            os.remove(r"C:\Users\temai\test2\video" + f"\{current_mess_name}")
            terminate(current_file)
    if mes.text == 'Проклясть':
        os.remove(r"C:\Users\temai\test2\images" + f"\{current_mess_name}")
        terminate(current_file)


def p_info(mes):
    global p_inform
    p_inform = mes.text
    bot.send_message(mes.chat.id, 'Пришли свое фото')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(mes, reg_photo)

def v_info(mes):
    global v_inform
    v_inform = mes.text
    bot.send_message(mes.chat.id, text='Пришли свое видео')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(mes, reg_video)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def reg_photo(mes):
    file_info = bot.get_file(mes.photo[len(mes.photo) - 1].file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    src = r"C:\Users\temai\test2\images\photo_" + mes.photo[1].file_id
    with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
    log('photo_'+mes.photo[1].file_id, mes.chat.username, p_inform)
    bot.send_message(mes.chat.id, text='Ваше фото в очереди на одобрение',reply_markup=start_kb())



    

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['video'])
def reg_video(mes):
    file_info = bot.get_file(mes.video.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    src =  r"C:\Users\temai\test2\video\vid_" + mes.video.file_id
    with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
    log('vid_'+ mes.video.file_id, mes.chat.username, v_inform)
    bot.send_message(mes.chat.id, text='Ваше видео в очереди на одобрение',reply_markup=start_kb())


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Ошибка:

```
2023-11-24 20:38:53,130 (__init__.py:1083 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Threaded polling exception: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object"
2023-11-24 20:38:53,135 (__init__.py:1085 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Exception traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\temai\test2\env\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling      
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "c:\Users\temai\test2\env\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 147, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "c:\Users\temai\test2\env\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 90, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\temai\test2\env\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 6801, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\temai\test2\main.py", line 75, in text
    bot.send_message(admin_id, text='Новых публикаций нет', reply_markup=[wait_kb])
  File "c:\Users\temai\test2\env\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1549, in send_message
    apihelper.send_message(
  File "c:\Users\temai\test2\env\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 264, in send_message
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload, method='post')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\temai\test2\env\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 162, in _make_request
    json_result = _check_result(method_name, result)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\temai\test2\env\Lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 189, in _check_result
    raise ApiTelegramException(method_name, result, result_json)
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object
"
```

Всем привет, создаю бота, уже вроде как почти получилось, а тут такой ахтунг, помогите, пожалуйста, подскажите, с чем может быть связана ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы почти везде передали клавиатуру в `reply_markup` по-разному, нельзя так.

Клавиатура (в вашем случае) везде должна быть передана в качестве функции.

```
def start_kb():
    kb_start = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True, row_width=5)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Послать фото")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Послать видео")
    kb_start.add(btn1, btn2)
    return kb_start

def wait_kb():
    kb_start = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True, row_width=5)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("/start")
    kb_start.add(btn1)
    return kb_start

def a_d_kb():
    kb = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    a = types.KeyboardButton('Одобрить')
    d = types.KeyboardButton('Проклясть')
    kb.add(a,d)
    return kb
    

bot.send_message(mes.chat.id, text='Приветствую тебя! Друг)', reply_markup=start_kb())
bot.send_message(admin_id, text='Новых публикаций нет', reply_markup=wait_kb()) # не представляю, зачем тут передавался [wait_kb]
bot.send_video(admin_id, video, caption=f'текст к видео:{current_mess_info}, создатель: {current_mess_author}', reply_markup=a_d_kb())
```